# How to target profile2 fields in a template

Tags: entities, users

I'm theming the display of user profile information managed by profile2 using a custom template, user-profile.tpl.php. I want to hide specific profile2 fields, and also check the value of others. However, looking at the $user_profile, field values are nested deeply in a profile, under the $pid, so I'm not sure how to cleanly target these in a template. So, my questions:

1. What is the best way to render a **single** profile2 field when working in a template?
2. What is the best way to hide a given profile2 field?

It's easy to hide a profile, or the title for a profile:

```
hide($user_profile['profile_main']);
$user_profile['profile_main']['#title'] = NULL;
```

But I'm not sure how to work with individual profile2 fields.

Note: based on http://drupal.org/node/1300460 (unanswered)